# Typescript: How to add type check for history object in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following piece of code, which receives a history object as prop:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ history }) => (
        <div className={styles.body}>
            <div className={styles.cta}>
                <FloatingActionButton onClick={() => history.push(routes[4].path)}>
                    <span>Click me</span>
                </FloatingActionButton>
            </div>
        </div>
);
```

How do I add typecheck for this history prop, **which is received by wrapping it's parent with withRouter HOC**? One way I could think of is to write something like this:

```
interface Props {
    history: {
        push(url: string): void;
    };
}
```

But I'm sure this is not the right way, because rest of the properties of the history object are being lost.

Can you suggest the right way of doing this?

**UPDATED the code based on @Oblosys's answer**

```
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
   /* Parent component's props*/
}

class Parent extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    render() {
        return <ChildComponent history={this.props.history} />;
    }
}

//Child component related stuff
interface ChildComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {}

const ChildComponent: React.SFC<ChildComponentProps> = (props) => (
  <div className={styles.body}>
     <div className={styles.cta}>
         <FloatingActionButton onClick={() => history.push(routes[4].path)}>
            <span>Click me</span>
         </FloatingActionButton>
     </div>
   </div>
);

function mapStateToProps(state: types.AppState) {
    /* related code */
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<types.AppState>{
    /* related code */
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Parent));
```

But, now I'm getting the following error:

```
Type '{ history: History; }' is not assignable to type 'ChildComponentProps'.
    Property 'match' is missing in type '{ history: History; }'
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can use the `RouteComponentProps` interface, which declares all props passed by `withRouter`:

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
..
interface ChildComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
  /* other props for ChildComponent */
}
const ChildComponent : React.SFC<ChildComponentProps> = ({ history }) => (
  ..
);
```

The type parameter to `RouteComponentProps` is the type of the `params` property in `match`, so you won't need it unless you're matching named path segments.

Alternatively, if `history` doesn't come from `withRouter` but is passed by itself as a prop, you can import the type from `history`:

```
import { History } from 'history';
..
interface ChildComponentProps {
  history : History
  /* other props for ChildComponent */
}
const ChildComponent : React.SFC<ChildComponentProps> = ({ history }) => (
  ..
);
```

Comment: Now im getting the following error:
Type '{ history: History; }' is not assignable to type 'ChildComponentProps'.
    Property 'match' is missing in type '{ history: History; }'

Comment: If you wrap `ChildComponent` in `withRouter` you won't need to explicitly pass the `history`.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution in case you want to pass only `history`.

Comment: When do you import X from `history`, what is this history package? Why do I not see it in package.json anywhere? I'm using the Parcel bundler

Comment: This one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/history. You'll have to put it in your package.json yourself.

Comment: When I try to use, <ChildComponent /> in VSCode, I can't see the props that `ChildComponent` can accept. any solutions to that?

Comment: If you don't wish to import `history` (because it's a transitive dependency, not a direct dependency), you may do `import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router"` and then use the type `RouteComponentProps["history"]`

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct way, but `ReturnType<typeof useHistory>` also gives me the correct typing for "history"

Answer (score 29):

The simplest solution I found

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

....

interface Foo{
  history: RouteComponentProps["history"];
  location: RouteComponentProps['location'];
  match: RouteComponentProps['match'];
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me with TS > 4.0. I had to do `RouteComponentProps["history"]`. Still a very useful tip, if you could adjust the answer - that would be great!

Answer (score 11):

For React 16.8 with hooks:

```
...
import {withRouter, RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router-dom';
...
const ChildComponent: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = ({history}) => {
...
}
```