# typing a HOC component that's using both withRouter and connect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following stack:

```
react@16.13.1
react-dom@16.13.1
react-redux@7.2.0
react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

I followed the approach suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342714/274677) on how to type-check a HOC component created with `withRouter` and it's working fine. E.g. the following component typechecks:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

type Props = RouteComponentProps<any>;

class Test extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.history.push("foo");
  };

  render() {
    return <div>foo</div>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(Test);
```

The problem arises when I wish to also link the component to the Redux store using `connect`. The following code fails to typecheck:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from "react-redux";

import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

type RootState = { foo: number };

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
  foo: state.foo;
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, null);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

type Props = PropsFromRedux & RouteComponentProps<any>;

class Test extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.history.push("foo"); // TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'never'.
  };

  render() {
    return <div>foo</div>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(connector(Test));
```

Specifically, I get:

```
TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Two questions:

1. why is the type of `props` evaluated as `never`?
2. how to properly typecheck a HOC component that's created with a successive application of both `withRouter` and `connect`?

Comment: Isn't that any of the `PropsFromRedux` nor `RouteComponentProps` mentions `history`?

Comment: @user0101 if that were the case, then the first code listing wouldn't typecheck either. Accordingly, it follows that `RouteComponentProps` does declare `history`. But somehow, when the `RouteComponentProps` type gets combined with the output of `ConnectedProps` then we have this type checking issue which I cannot explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### never

If you start hovering over some props, you'll see that there's a lot of `never` going on.

Props is `never` because `PropsFromRedux` is `never` (the union of `never` and anything is always `never`).

```
type ConnectedProps<TConnector> = TConnector extends InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<infer TInjectedProps, any> ? TInjectedProps : never
```

As seen above, the `ConnectedProps` utility type returns the first generic of `InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps`.

`PropsFromRedux`, which is `ConnectedProps<typeof connector>` evaluates to `never` because the the type of `connected` is `InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<never, {}>`.

So tracing it backwards, we see that the core problem is the type of `connected`.

### void

You've actually made an error in your `mapStateToProps` function because you forgot to wrap it in parentheses, so you aren't actually returning anything!  This alone won't fix your issues (it just replaces `never` with `void`), but it is a prerequisite for the other fixes.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  foo: state.foo;
});
```

Now it returns `{foo: number}` instead of `void`.

### Solution 1

The reason that the inferred type of `connected` goes wrong is because you are setting the `dispatch` argument to `null`.  There are [14 different overloads](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5454930b2034878b7cf0d749a1272a5e37f41bfa/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L192) for the `connect` function, but the only ones that allow the second argument to be `null` are those that set the third or fourth arguments.  It is expected that if you don't need to set the second `dispatch` argument, you should leave it off entirely.

When we get rid of the `null` argument, suddenly everything is fine and `this.props.history` gets type `History<any>`.

```
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);
// => InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<{foo: number} & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, {}>

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
// => {foo: number} & DispatchProp<AnyAction>

type Props = PropsFromRedux & RouteComponentProps<any>;
// => {foo: number} & DispatchProp<AnyAction> & RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>
```

### Solution 2

I like my `types` and `interfaces` to be independent from my code, so I don't love `typeof connector`.  We know what props we want to be extracting from redux, so we could just type them directly.

```
type PropsFromRedux = {
  foo: number;
  dispatch: Dispatch;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](http://typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG9EIBXGJAYV0gDsluYACjjABnADRwA7sBgALBCzZQ4AXzjZcBIuhgBaHKyRRdAE1xkqNaPEZoI3XhgmcHSDEhNCIo1epx5CYj0iE2YADwtKKhgATzAkJggYAGUYFDY4AF4GdQgIAC44bmYQACMjVQooyjtuEXgQFDBU9KQAFQgvH2yACnrWwoUklrYASiyAPjge%20io4XIK4frYAOkw8qpVRqqpa%20rhaxxhoLIP7I57G5rS2Dq6RbaoAeifJuABJbkwjFFKAGw4XHsfBgAFFuLIUNw0EYAOoyWT3AA89HWi2KZSMagAZHAACLAERgdJoRHCJEAQW4MQpGGA9gmEnoKgmVGicQS9wAYv5kKEwqcXEcPMjYvEIJgzq4MNAJlUXm9UXlChjylAcfjCcSYKSupTqbSYPTuKzqmLOcIRKdubyPOE4LiFIZOOBgfxkVCYnLnq9MlMleiSmqNQSiSSyd59TS6QyHUxnUDeO7LUjPRIRsA0C42GEYBJPabdn8UCIrW0kPskLm%20CYrcgdCsXTwQUj7kyWQw5mdXUmYASTABZFj8U49cZ%20zuUebzOSElZgS0rWSE45QGLz5giWQ9fBo-DbOAK7gQOAgaAJIw4KAAQi7Kh2U7gRG4JiMY8n06fSBgzCg3DgSImMAABuExokiTxAaBVTzCoVBwdUVa0PAr6YCgzB-PA0hyE6Sg9Icbirj05b1KM2xAA)